# Neo4J: Why are the new native relationship indexes much slower than APOC?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I set up the new native indexes on the relationships in my DB (Neo4J 3.5.17 or Neo4J 4.0.3).

To set up those indexes I used

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createRelationshipIndex("BY",["BY"],['user','context','statement']);
```

When I query the relationships with certain properties using something like:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships('BY','context:(id1 id2 id3)') 
YIELD relationship RETURN relationship;
```

It works much much slower than the APOC procedures I used before, such as:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('BY','context:(id1 id2 id3)') 
YIELD rel RETURN rel;
```

I have two questions:

1) Is it normal that APOC indexes are much faster than the "native" new Neo4J ones and that the new ones sometimes even crash my system?

2) Is there any other type of native indexes I could attach to my relationships, like not the `fulltext` ones but maybe something else, something faster?

3) If the answer is "Yes" to the two questions above, what was the point of introducing those new relationship indexes and deprecating the APOC ones if they worked so well for years? Like at least you could leave the APOC ones as an option, but now they are removed... Yes, it was not very convenient to set up triggers, but APOC was super fast and reliable. This new indexing system is waaaaay too slow. Any answer on that from Neo4J developers?

Comment: Can you share your query profiles? Feel free to drop me an email.

Comment: Also how big are the texts that you index?

Comment: and how big is your id-list

Comment: just tried it on 500k rels returning 12k rels and it was 25ms